# Local fixed disk cannot be accessed from service

Tags: c#, service, vmware, windows-server-2012

I'm experiencing the following strange behaviour:

A C# service fails to do any operations on local disk D: (e.g. check if a directory exists), while the console version wrapping the same assembly, has no problem whatsoever. Both are running under the same user account, which is member of the local Administrators group.
When loggon on interactively, this same user also has no problems accessing drive D:\ using Windows explorer.

Inserting the following diagnostic code:

```
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            string label = drive.IsReady ? String.Format(" - {0}", drive.VolumeLabel) : " - drive not ready";
            string driveMessage = string.Format("Drive {0} - {1}{2}", drive.Name, drive.DriveType, label);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("NxG SiteService", driveMessage, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }
```

shows that drive D: is a fixed disk, which is "not ready"?

Can someone please explain me why a fixed disk can be "not ready" when accessed from a service?

The environment is: Windows 2012 Server, running on a VMWare ESXi host v. 5.5.0

Comment: Perhaps 'poll' it till it becomes ready? Perhaps it is mapped to some SAN storage and takes a few seconds to respond.

Comment: Have you tried a delayed Service start? Maybe the service just has to start later. Or does the Service also display this behavior if you start it manually?

Comment: @M C - The service also displays this behaviour when it is started manually.

Comment: Have you tried running your service under a dedicated user account? AFAIK it is a bad practise to run Services under a 'real'-user account. Also check the NTFS permissions.

Comment: @M C - I've tried with different user accounts including a domain account which belongs to the local Administrators group, and with the local Administrator account... to no avail. The NTFS permissions should be OK, since the same user can access it from a desktop session. Anyways, I made the user account running the service the owner of the root directory (+propagate to all files and subdirs), still no success.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We found the cause & solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/179c72b2-2957-43a0-8798-472e907a6e55/access-denied-issue-with-server-2012-only-on-secondary-drive-not-c

Comment: Please add the solution and not just a link to your answer.